# Java scheduleAtFixedDelay stop

Tags: java, multithreading, schedule

how can i make such code working?

```
public void start()
{
    ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleWithFixedDelay(new Thread(), 1000, 1000);
}

public class Thread implements Runnable
{
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        i++;
        if(i==5)
            //TODO stop this thread
    }
}
```

I want to stop the Thread after i == 5

Edit:
It can be done like that:

```
public void start()
{
    ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().schedule(new Thread(), 1000);
}

public class Thread implements Runnable
{
    int i = 0;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while(i!=5)
        {
            i++;
            try {Thread.sleep(1000);} catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();}
        }
    }
}
```

But still if anybody have idea how to make it with scheduleWithFixedDelay i would be glad to know the answer :)

Comment: It's `scheduleWithFixedDelay` not `scheduleAtFixedDelay`.

Comment: Do you want to keep using the pool after you stop this thread or not?

Comment: I want to use multiple threads at the same time. Sorry about scheduleAtFixedDelay/scheduleWithFixedDelay. I have got it changed in class that overrides ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor and didnt notice it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stopping a `ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor` task from within itself is a bit more convoluted. You could try to pass back the `ScheduledFuture` to the task itself and call `cancel` (not thread-safe but since you have a delay of 1000 ms it should be enough):

```
public void start()
{
    Task t = new Task();
    ScheduledFuture sf = ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleAtFixedDelay(t, 1000, 1000);
    t.setFuture(sf);
}

class Task implements Runnable {

    private int i = 0;
    private ScheduledFuture sf;

    public void setFuture(ScheduledFuture sf) {
        this.sf = sf;
    }

    public void run() {
        i++;
        if(i==5)
            sf.cancel(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().shutdown(); will shutdown all of my threads and i want only this one :/

Answer (score 0):

You could just use `this.stop()`.

Edit: didn't notice it would keep FixedDelay-ing, so:

```
public void start()
{
    ThreadPoolManager.getInstance().scheduleAtFixedDelay(new Thread(new MyThread()), 1000, 1000);
}

public class MyThread implements Runnable
{
    int i = 0;
    boolean keepGoing = true;
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        if (keepGoing)
        {
            i++;
            System.out.println("Thread in " + i);
            if(i==5)
                keepGoing = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @A. R. S. because we only want one `i` for the program. well I guess if the class is reused then no but that was just what I did :P edit: yeah I guess I'll change that :P

Comment: i thought about that solution but actually my program is a lot more complicated and this method will run quite often and i dont want to let unfinished threads in it.